# From GCH straight to cardinal arithmetic = max?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Working in ZF+GCH where GCH is expressed in the algebraic form  "Never $\mathfrak{n} < \mathfrak{m} < 2^\mathfrak{n} $ for infinite cardinals" is there a simple and direct proof, preferably of an algebraic nature and bypassing AC, that $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n}=\mathfrak{m}\cdot\mathfrak{n}=\max (\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n})$.

Usually given ZF the arithmetic of cardinals is developed and it turns out to have an ordered ring structure with exponentiation. Then AC is introduced and cardinal arithmetic is rendered trivial, except for exponentiation. I want to go straight from ZF+GCH to cardinal arithmetic being trivial, without going from ZF+GCH to AC then ZF+AC to cardinal arithmetic being trivial.

By an algebraic style of proof I mean similar in style to this:-

... but then $2\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}$, because $\mathfrak{m}\le2\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{m}\le2^{\mathfrak{m}}+2^{\mathfrak{m}}=2\cdot2^{\mathfrak{m}}=2^{\mathfrak{m}+1}=2^{\mathfrak{m}}$ and no intermediates by GCH so $\mathfrak{m}=2\mathfrak{m}$ or $2\mathfrak{m}=2^{\mathfrak{m}}$, but $2\mathfrak{m}<2^{\mathfrak{m}}$ ...

Comment: Certainly cardinals do not form an ordered ring. What is the additive inverse of $\aleph_0$?

Comment: (I assume your goal is to avoid the use of ordinals as well as choice.)

Comment: @Andrés: Second paragraph, first sentence (the second line, in particular).

Comment: I should have said ring-like, intent was ring-like laws such as commutivity, distributivity, etc. Acknowledge not an actual ring.

Comment: Hi Andres, if I understand your question properly, I would be OK with a simple non-AC theory of vonNeumann-style ordinals so I can define cardinals as special ordinals rather than equivalence classes.

Comment: How is $\max(\mathfrak m,\mathfrak n\}$ defined?

Comment: Excellent question, we know that AC makes $\min(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n})$ meaningful, so since GCH implies AC, GCH must be able to make it meaningful as well. This would have to be part of the algebraic development I am after.

Comment: Mark, if you define cardinal as only initial ordinals, then ZF cannot prove the existence of exponent. More specifically, $2^\kappa$ is always a cardinal if and only if choice holds. And so if you haven't proved that $2^\kappa$ is a cardinal, how do you apply the arithmetic operations to it?

Comment: Thanks Asaf, seem to be in a catch 22. To define cardinals without resorting to equivalence classes requires AC. Even though GCH implies AC, GCH can't be expressed in algebraic terms like "Never $\mathfrak{n}<\mathfrak{m}<2^\mathfrak{m}$ or used to prove things about  $\min(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n})$ without first having AC. So a set-like version of GHC like $X\prec \wp Y \implies X\preceq Y$ seems to be required first, giving a set-like version of AC, then cardinals, then loop back and prove cardinal algebra results.